# TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call: QLineEdit(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_EncryptionbyPyQt5' l

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\gakas\pythonProject5\shifr2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QApplication, QLineEdit
from datetime import datetime
import sys


class Ui_EncryptionbyPyQt5(object):
    def setupUi(self, EncryptionbyPyQt5):
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setObjectName("EncryptionbyPyQt5")
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setEnabled(True)
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.resize(800, 608)
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setStyleSheet("background-color:#22222e")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(EncryptionbyPyQt5)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 80, 301, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #6B8E23;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 80, 151, 61))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color:#6B8E23;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;    \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"background-color: #90EE90\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 210, 311, 31))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #6B8E23;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 300, 301, 61))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #6B8E23;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 420, 311, 61))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #6B8E23;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 500, 151, 61))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color:#6B8E23;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;    \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"background-color: #90EE90\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 50, 261, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 180, 261, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 270, 261, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 390, 261, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(EncryptionbyPyQt5)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(EncryptionbyPyQt5)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(EncryptionbyPyQt5)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(EncryptionbyPyQt5)

    def retranslateUi(self, EncryptionbyPyQt5):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        EncryptionbyPyQt5.setWindowTitle(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "Выбрать файл"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "Зашифровать"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "Расшифровать"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "ваывавы"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "Запустить"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "Введите имя файла"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "            Выберите тип"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "      Введите ключ от 1 до 90"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("EncryptionbyPyQt5", "            Куда вывести"))

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_3 = QLineEdit()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.openFileNameDialog)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    EncryptionbyPyQt5 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_EncryptionbyPyQt5()
    ui.setupUi(EncryptionbyPyQt5)
    EncryptionbyPyQt5.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


def openFileNameDialog(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    global filelist
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Text file", "", "Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
    if not fileName:
        fileName = None
    print(fileName)
    self.lineedit.setText(fileName)


def ciphering(self):
    self.filename = self.lineedit.text()
    self.optfilename = self.lineedit2.text()
    self.process = self.combo.currentText()
    self.key = self.lineedit1.text()

    ##########################

    password_key = int(self.key)
    store = ''
    Letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' \
              '!@#$%&*(){}[]<>/\|";:\n-=+.,?0123456789'
    now = datetime.now()
    print(now)

    option_1 = self.process
    if option_1 == 'Зашифровать':
        print('Ok Sir!..You Selected({0})'.format(option_1))
        file = self.filename
        if password_key == 0:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Incorrect Encryption Key Entered",
                                 "Please enter Encryption key in range of 1 - 90.")
        else:
            print("password key: ", password_key)
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                try:
                    file = open(file, 'r').read()
                    print('Congratualtions output file saved.')
                except:
                    print('Filename Error: Please! Enter File name in txt form/Enter correct address of file.')
                for i in file:
                    if i in Letters:
                        number = Letters.find(i)
                        try:
                            number = number + int(password_key)
                        except:
                            print('Key Error: You Enter a Incorrect key.')
                            break
                        if number >= len(Letters):
                            number = number - len(Letters)
                        elif number < 0:
                            number = number + len(Letters)
                        store = store + Letters[number]
                    else:
                        store = store + i
                    save_file = open('{}.txt'.format(self.optfilename), 'w')
                    save_file.write(store)
                    save_file.close()
                QMessageBox.about(self, "Process completed.",
                                  "Congratulations! {} successfully done.".format(self.process))
            else:
                QMessageBox.critical(self, "Filename Error", "Please! Enter txt form only.")


    elif option_1 == 'Расшифровать':
        print('Ok Sir!..You Selected({0})'.format(option_1))

        file = self.filename
        if password_key == 0:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Incorrect Encryption Key Entered",
                                 "Please enter Encryption key in range of 1 - 90.")
        else:
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                try:
                    file = open(file, 'r').read()
                    print('Congratualtions output file saved.')

                except:
                    print('Filename Error: Please! Enter File name in txt form.')
                for i in file:
                    if i in Letters:
                        number = Letters.find(i)
                        try:
                            number = number - int(password_key)
                        except:
                            print('Key Error: You Enter a Incorrect key.')
                            break
                        if number >= len(Letters):
                            number = number - len(Letters)
                        elif number < 0:
                            number = number + len(Letters)
                        store = store + Letters[number]
                    else:
                        store = store + i
                    save_file = open('{}.txt'.format(self.optfilename), 'w')
                    save_file.write(store)
                    save_file.close()
                QMessageBox.about(self, "Process completed.",
                                  "Congratulations! {} successfully done.".format(self.process))
            else:
                QMessageBox.critical(self, "Filename Error", "Please! Enter txt form only.")


class MyWindow:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Why the program doesn't work?

Comment: Why did you add nonsense filler text to your question instead of actual more useful details as requested?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Could you provide a summary on what you were trying to do and the tools/methods you were using to achieve it? This will help people better understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

The error message "arguments did not match any overloaded call" indicates that the program is trying to call a function with arguments that do not match any of its defined signatures. In this case, the error message specifically mentions a QLineEdit function and specifies that the first argument has an unexpected type.

This error is typically caused by passing the wrong type of argument to a function. In this case, it looks like the program is trying to pass an instance of the Ui_EncryptionbyPyQt5 class as the first argument to the QLineEdit function, but this is not a valid argument for that function. To fix this error, you will need to make sure that you are passing the correct type of argument to the QLineEdit function. This may require changing the code that calls the function or modifying the function itself.